# Check console logs (and stop build if needed)

Tags: jenkins, logging, plugins, build

We are using Jenkins (on Linux) to manage our builds.

I want to monitor the console output of all currently running jobs and abort the build if any matched pattern / exception / error is found.

For example, if the console output has IndentationError(when the job is running), I would like to automatically stop the build.

Please let me know if there are any plugins or solutions for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins will stop any build when a tool returns a non-zero exit code. If you want your build to exit on the first error, then you should configure the tools you are calling from jenkins to exit as soon as an error occurs (through command line flags etc.). Parsing console output for an error is a hacky solution at best.

Comment: If I have 500+ jobs running on my server, should I be configuring those for each job individually or can I achieve this via any plugin or script?